# Passing image data buffers to Windows Runtime on Windows Phone 8

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8, winprt

I'm trying to find an efficient way to pass an image data buffer to a Windows Runtime Component on Windows **Phone** 8, minimizing the number of times the buffer data needs to be copied. A similar, but more general, question has been asked before:

See [Passing images from Windows (Phone) Runtime Components (c++/cx) to Native c++ Algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539876/passing-images-from-windows-phone-runtime-components-c-cx-to-native-c-al)

**Background**

An MSDN article on the topic can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn182761.aspx). It suggests using a `WriteableBitmap` that can expose the underlying pixel buffer as an `IBuffer` object, which allows the native component to manipulate the data in-place without copying the buffer first.

See [How to get access to WriteableBitmap.PixelBuffer pixels with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708755/how-to-get-access-to-writeablebitmap-pixelbuffer-pixels-with-c)

However, the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging` namespace that the `WriteableBitmap` is part of is not available for Windows Phone 8, only Windows 8. Instead one can use `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap`, but it only gives access to the image pixel data in the form of an int[]. One way of converting this to an `IBuffer` is:

```
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;

private static IBuffer AsBuffer(WriteableBitmap bitmap)
{
  int[] p = bitmap.Pixels;
  int len = p.Length * 4;
  byte[] arr = new byte[len];
  Buffer.BlockCopy(p, 0, arr, 0, len);
  return arr.AsBuffer(); // Part of System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime
}
```

but it involves unnecessary copying of the buffer.

On the other hand, passing byte arrays of data has its disadvantages according to this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh975353.aspx). Basically, in the Windows Runtime, parameters are either for input or for output, never both, which means that some copying is necessary in the end.

**Sought answer**

- How do I efficiently pass the image data through the Windows Runtime layer?
- What RT classes are suitable when passing images and when passing video streams? Simple arrays or more complex buffers?

Comment: Just an FYI, `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap` is available in Windows Phone 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Camera api for native code is the way to go:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj571202

you'll get the data directly in your c++ WinRT component code.
see an example here :
http://library.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Getting_started_with_the_Camera_APIs_for_native_code

Comment: Your suggestion works only when capturing new images, not for photos or otherwise stored images.

Comment: i wonder if you could find a solution for this. I have a byte[] which i assigned to the native component's buffer and thus processed in native. Now, I am stuck at how to bind this to a WriteableBitmap. A similar copying of all bytes to a int[] would work probably but with performance degradation. and i guess there is not a reinterpret_cast thing in .net.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [IRandomAccessStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.irandomaccessstream(v=win.10).aspx) (or it's concrete class [InMemoryRandomAccessStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.inmemoryrandomaccessstream.aspx)) to exchange raw data between WinRT components. Depending on what you want to achieve, it can be a good option to avoid copy.